# Managing multiple Vims (vim and MacVim)

Tags: vim, osx

My machine came with Vim 7.3 and I just installed MacVim 7.4, so now I'm juggling both and I'm not sure how to manage the two. I'm plagued by questions like:

- Should I remove the older version?
- Where should MacVim be located?

Currently MacVim.app is in `/Applications`, and I see a couple executables at `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim` and `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`.

The pre-installed Vim 7.3 is sitting at `/usr/bin/vim`.

I'd like to be able to use 7.4 both from the terminal and in MacVim. I haven't installed MacVim's "mvim" script and not sure I will.

What is the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an alias for `vim` in your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias vim=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
```

With this the Bash will replace ´vim `with`/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`, when you type something like this:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

So you don't need to remove `/usr/bin/vim`, which is probably a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Solved my dilemma *and* taught me how to set an alias :)

Comment: I just noticed that although setting the above alias did fix my problem, `which vim` still shows the older version `use/bin/vim`. Is that to do with the order of things in my `$PATH`? Should I do anything about that?

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then. It explains the problem. It basically comes down to the fact that `which` only looks at `$PATH` and thinks like `type` look also at aliases.